# How to create automation test flow with JMeter?

Tags: api, automation, jmeter

Is it possible to create Automation test flow with Jmeter?

So that all the Jmeter tests run it self and then I just gets the result generated for it?

Also can we add different scenarios for an application in that automation?

It would be great if some one can share on how to start from scratch for JMeter Automation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to have "Jmeter tests run it self ".

JMeter tests can be invoked in multiple ways:

1. [Command-line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
2. [Ant task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter)
3. [Maven plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin/)

All options provide results either in [.jtl](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) file format or in [HTML](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

If you  want to invoke the tests in unattended manner - you can either rely on your operating system tasks scheduling mechanisms like [Windows Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) or [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) or even use a [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) tool like [Jenkins](http://jenkins.io/), all of them are capable of kicking off the arbitrary tasks depending on various criteria, produce reports, display trends, etc.